# Monthly Count In MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I'm going to do monthly COUNT.
I want to COUNT the data from now to 15 months ago.I want it to be marked 0 in the month when there is no data.

Here is My Table

PeopleFruit

| Id | Fruit | People | CreatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | John | 2020-11-13 |
| 2 | Banana | Katie | 2020-11-25 |
| 3 | Kiwi | Sam | 2021-03-03 |
| 4 | Apple | Katie | 2021-04-12 |
| 5 | Apple | Katie | 2021-04-24 |
| 6 | Apple | John | 2021-04-30 |
| 7 | Banana | Sam | 2021-09-02 |
| 8 | Banana | Katie | 2021-11-11 |
| 9 | Apple | Sam | 2021-12-12 |
| 10 | Kiwi | John | 2021-12-15 |

I want to know the fruit COUNT by month so that people don't overlap.
ex)If you look at Apple in April(Month 4), Katie chose it twice and John chose it once, but because Katie overlaps, COUNT became 2.

I used this query.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(createdAt,'%y.%m') m, COUNT(DISTINCT(People)) as count
FROM  PeopleFruit
WHERE createdAt > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL - 15 MONTH)
  AND Fruit = 'Apple'
GROUP BY m;
```

result is

| m | count |
| --- | --- |
| 20.11 | 1 |
| 21.04 | 2 |
| 21.12 | 1 |

But this is the result I want.

| m | count |
| --- | --- |
| 21.12 | 1 |
| 21.11 | 0 |
| 21.10 | 0 |
| 21.09 | 0 |
| 21.08 | 0 |
| 21.07 | 0 |
| 21.06 | 0 |
| 21.05 | 0 |
| 21.04 | 2 |
| 21.03 | 0 |
| 21.02 | 0 |
| 21.01 | 0 |
| 20.12 | 0 |
| 20.11 | 1 |
| 20.10 | 0 |

What should I do?

Comment: *But this is the result I want.* Generate base year-month table then LEFT JOIN your data table and group.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifer_. Remove those extra parentheses and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT People) as count`, to make code clearer!

Comment: Your MySQL version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use `RECURSIVE CTE` like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE months(m) AS (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') m
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(m, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) m FROM months
    WHERE m > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MONTH)
) SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(months.m,'%y.%m') m,
    COALESCE(count, 0)  count
FROM months
NATURAL LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(createdAt,'%Y-%m-01') m, COUNT(DISTINCT(People)) as count
  FROM  PeopleFruit
  WHERE createdAt > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL - 15 MONTH) AND Fruit = 'Apple'
  GROUP BY m
) months_count ;
```

[MySQL recursive CTE test](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/bc0948aafc1d32e73e8ac3af11ca6440/)

Comment: Thank you. It works very well. You're a genius. Can you explain the principle a bit?